# Error message "cannot implicitly convert type 'system.drawing.color' to 'system.windows.media.color'"

Tags: c#, wpf, save, color-picker

I am struggling with some WPF issues. This is just one of them:

```
{backgroundColor.SelectedColor = Properties.Settings.Default.backgroundColorSt;}
```

When I write this into my initiliaze() section, I face an error like:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'system.drawing.color' to
>   'system.windows.media.color'

How can I convert System.Drawing.Color into System.Windows:Media.Color to save the color which I choose from colorPicker?

Comment: So explicitly convert it the hard way.

Comment: I actually do not understand your comment :(  but I want to choose a color from ColorPicker and after that i reopen that section i want to see the color i choose before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the type `System.Drawing.Color` for your `backgroundColorSt` setting in the first place. Instead, use `System.Windows.Media.Color`.

In the `Settings` page of your project properties,

- go to the `backgroundColorSt` line
- click the `Type` ComboBox,
- choose `Browse...`,
- select the `PresentationCore` assembly,
- then the namespace `System.Windows.Media`,
- then the type `Color`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert between them you could do this:

```
System.Drawing.Color drawingColor = Color.Red;
System.Windows.Media.Color mediaColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(drawingColor.A, drawingColor.R, drawingColor.G, drawingColor.B);
```

For your specific problem I suggest storing it as string:

```
//Save the Color from Colorpicker as HEX value to Settings:
System.Drawing.Color color = backgroundColor.SelectedColor;
//Assuming you store to string:
Properties.Settings.Default.backgroundColorSt = "#" + color.R.ToString("X2") + color.G.ToString("X2") + color.B.ToString("X2");

//Later when reading the value from settings simply do this:
System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Properties.Settings.Default.backgroundColorSt);
```

Comment: Thank you very much i wll try this :)